# Weird error when writting OR conditionals in PHP

Tags: php, conditional-statements

This error has been bugging me for a long time and I can't find an answer anywhere on the Internet, even using PHP official documentation.

When I write if statements with multiple conditions like this

```
if ((empty($user) == true) || (isset($user->data) == false)) {
    //...
}
```

PHP says "Call to undefined function  ()".

Then I try this alternative:

```
if (empty($user) == true || isset($user->data) == false) {
    //...
}
```

And PHP says Call to undefined function  isset().

PHP version 5.5.15.

Comment: try to check the function is exists or not with this http://php.net/manual/en/function.method-exists.php , if there is no method of isset you can reinstall it or, you can change isset with !empty. try to var_dump(isset($user->data));

Comment: `isset` has been around from the beginning.  So check the line numbers and re-evaluate your diagnosis.  Don't forget you can add line breaks to help you in determining the proper error location.

Comment: Also, really no need to check for `== true` and `== false` can be checked by the `!` operator.

Comment: I'm guessing there is a invisible character after `|| `

Comment: Try to re-type everything instead of copy & paste. As said by the above comments, the line can be simplified to `if(empty($user) || !isset($user->data)) { }`

Answer (score 2):

By chance I just found the answer to my own problem. I cannot believe it, after all this time.

You're right @Musa

```
if (empty($user) == true || isset($user->data) == false) {

if (empty($user) == true || isset($user->data) == false) {
```

I realized something was wrong reconstructing both conditionals and looking at Sublime's syntax highlighting.

I use alt gr to write the pipe symbol and sometimes I left it pressed more than I should and I end up writting alt gr + space. It results in an invisible character that I believed to be a space.

[image: Sublime code screen capture]

Thanks everyone.

Answer (score 0):

How about:

```
if (empty($user) || !isset($user->data)) {
    //...
}
```

Comment: This verses the `== true` or `== false` equivalent does not matter. As your answer is simply a matter of *style* and not *functionality*. Visually there aren't any problems with the OPs code pertaining to the error messages (not taking into the invincible character).

Comment: Fair. I guess my point was that, in trying to figure out where his error may be, I found myself trying to count how many open parentheses he had.  This is easier to track.  With that said, never would have guessed an invisible character.  Very interesting!